# Azure Blob Storage "Method not found" with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-storage

I have the folowing error when I apply the method `GetBlockBlobReference()` on a azure storage container. I can fetch this container using the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet, I can also see al the methods when I navigate into this Nuget, but at the compilation some methods are not found.

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   AffluenceFunction. GoogleAnalytics: Method not found: 'Void
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(System.IO.Stream,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AccessCondition,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobRequestOptions,
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext)'

On the internet everybody says "downgrade" the Azure Storage Nuget version but is not working. I have try with version 5, 6, 7 and even 9. **Im using .NET Framework 4.7 as a class library who is called by a Function Project on version 2.**

Some code (again the I can retreive the container):

```
    public void UploadFile( CloudBlobContainer container )
    {
        var filePathOnServer = Path.Combine("C:/temp/test/c.csv");

        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePathOnServer))
        {
            var filename = "c.csv"; // Trim fully pathed filename to just the filename
            var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

We use Azure Blob Storage excly the same way on other project (others version of .NET) and it work fine!

Thank you

Comment: If the answer works for you, please help mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the latest blob storage nuget package:  [Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Version 10.0.3.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob/)

Install it both on the class library and the azure function.

I have a test with .net 4.7 class library and azure function v2, it works.

The reason is that, `WindowsAzure.Storage` NuGet version 9.3 or below for .net core does only supports async method, so for function v2(which is .net core) does not have a definition `UploadFromStream()`. But in `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Version 10.0.3`, it does support async and non-async method for .net core project.